# Jenkins agent configuration issue in linux

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys, hosts-file, jenkins-agent

I am facing the below issue please have a look.

Searching for lokesh in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`
Searching for lokesh:22 in `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`

```
[06/04/20 12:59:45] [SSH] WARNING: No entry currently exists in the Known Hosts file for this host. Connections will be denied until this new host and its associated key is added to the Known Hosts file.
Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.", retrying in 15 seconds. There are 8 more retries left.
```

Answer (score 7):

You should add the ssh key (created on the slave) to your known hosts file of in the master (Jenkins user). Follow [this link](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux-academy/adding-a-jenkins-agent-node/)

Also you can try one more thing if this does not work. There is an option of **Host key verification strategy** in jenkins node setup.

Select **Non verifying verification strategy** and check.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: After adding every authentication possible including (Key & Password) based authentication I still couldn't get it work through Jenkins. But I was able to login through the shell as jenkins (with Key & Passwd, both worked)..  I was baffled. But then I used *Non verifying verification strategy* dropdown in Jenkins and the Agent got installed.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Use "Trust SSH Host Key" in the menu on the left-hand side of the agent configuration panel.

Answer (score 2):

run this on your Jenkins server:
ssh-keyscan -H ${IP-OF-AGENT} > ~/.ssh/known_hosts